# Generating rows and columns within a given range of numbers - PHP

Tags: php, html, input, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to build a little program to automatize a little task; in it, one can write two values (as inputs in a form) and then, in another page, numbers will be written in rows and columns with all the numbers within the range given.

The thing is... There will (almost always) be 500 numbers in the range, so I want the result to be displayed in 10 columns of 50 rows each, something like this image:

[image: What I would like to achieve]

I wanted the result page (the one with all the numbers) to THEN give the possibility to export this as xml or pdf, but that's another story..
By now, I just would like to get the display right.

I'm using HTML and PHP on XAMPP. I've been able to get the first column... but can't get to the generations of the others, like this (and so on until 50):

[image: First column of numbers]

So far, this is what I have, I'll put here my PHP code, because I don't think the HTML is relevant (but will post it too if it's needed) - (The values are passed by POST method)

```
    <?php

      $cont = 0;
      $i = 0;

      $arrayValues = range($valueFrom, $valueTo);

      if($cont <= 50){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++){
          echo "<p>$arrayValues[$i]</p>";
          $cont++;
        }
      echo "</tr>";
      }

     ?>
```

Also, using something like this --> [Use PHP to Generate HTML table with static Cell Count of MySQL Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057943/use-php-to-generate-html-table-with-static-cell-count-of-mysql-data) and worked ok, but I would the numbers displayed in columns... so not in rows (horizontally), so..

```
    YES    |    NO
   1 4 7   |    1  2  3
   2 5 8   |    4  5  6
   3 6 9   |    7  8  9
```

That's why I stopped trying with tables and just used a

tag for the result.

EDIT:
So, given the "start" value and "end" value for a range, I would like to be able to print all those values in 10 columns of 50 rows each (so when it reaches 50 rows in the first column, it automatically moves to a new column and so on), and vertically (like the little diagram I tried to put above this, in the "YES" side)

Any ideas or guidance will be appreciated! :) 
Have a nice rest of the week!

Comment: Did you have a *specific* question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hi! I've edited the post, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by splitting your range up into chunks and indexing into the resulting array of columns in a nested loop.

```
<table>
<?php
$valueFrom = 1;
$valueTo = 500;

$rowCount = 50;

$columns = array_chunk(range($valueFrom, $valueTo), $rowCount);

$columnCount = count($columns);

for ($row = 0; $row < $rowCount; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($column = 0; $column < $columnCount; $column++) {
        $number = $columns[$column][$row] ?? '';
        echo "<td>$number</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @dont-panic Oh my, I've tried nested loops (kind of similiar to the two-dimensional arrays' exercises we used to do at uni when I was starting out with programming haha, but had a hard time remembering and trying to find out exactly WHAT to look up on the internet) but couldn't make them work.. I see what you mean know! Will be sure to test this tomorrow and mark it as answer if it works for me, thank you very much! :)